# limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow b^-}f(t)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous real-valued function on the bounded open interval $(a,b)$.

(a) Prove that the real limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow b^-}f(t)$ exists.

(b) what if $f$ is instead of "uniform" but bounded? It should not be true, but any counterexamples?

For (a), it's asking for the limit of $b$ approaching from the left. I want to use the definition of continuity by sequence, but $b\not\in(a,b)$, so I'm stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(A)$

Fix $\epsilon>0$. By uniform continuity, there is a $\delta>0$ such that when $x,y \in (b-\delta,b)$ we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Suppose $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is an arbitrary sequence in $(a,b)$. Suppose also that it converges to $b$.

Consider the sequence $\{f(a_n)\}_{n \geq 1}$. If we choose $M$ large enough so that for all $k,m > M$, $a_k, a_m  \in (b-\delta, b)$, we have

$$|f(a_k) - f(a_m)| < \epsilon$$

This implies $\{f(a_n)\}$ is Cauchy. Hence, the sequence converges with limit $L$. This limit $L$ must be independent of the sequence converging. If $\{b_n\}$ is another sequence converging to $b$ but $\{f(b_n)\}$ converges to some $L_1 \neq L$, the sequence $$c_n = 
\begin{cases}
a_n  & n \ \text{odd} \\
b_n & n \ \text{even}
\end{cases}$$

converges to $b$ but $\{f(c_n)\}$ doesn't converge, which yields a contradiction.

Hence, we can see that for every sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $(a,b)$ converging to $b$, $\{f(a_n)\}$ converges to the same number $L$, which means

$$\lim_{x \to b^{-}} f(x) = L$$

$(B)$

No. Consider $f(x) = \sin \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: Edited: the argument wasn't quite complete before.

Answer (score 1):

So, like you said, we can't show that $\lim\limits_{t\to b^-}f(t)=L$ because we don't know what $L$ is. Whenever you have no candidate for the limit of a sequence, it is good to consider using a Cauchy sequence instead. In this case, the Cauchy criterion for one-sided limits is as follows:

> $\lim\limits_{t\to b^-}f(t)$ exists if, for all sequences $\{t_n\}$ in $(a,b)$ converging to $b$ and for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that, if $m,n>N$, then $|f(t_m)-f(t_n)|<\epsilon$.

Now, since you have uniform continuity, the result follows almost immediately. Every sequence $\{t_n\}$ which you consider is eventually (read: after some $N$) within $(b-\delta,b)$ for every $\delta>0$. If this is the same $\delta$ from the definition of uniform continuity, then we automatically get $|f(t_m)-f(t_n)|<\epsilon$ for all $m,n>N$.